# C++ reset cin and cout

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stream, cin, cout

Ok so I have 3 functions that all represent a question that I need to answer. My first question is working with `cin` and `cout`, and is broken into parts. The problem is that after one part finishes, another part automatically takes the remainder of the input in the first part rather than asking for a new input. 
My problems lay in

```
//part B
char state[30];
cout << "Enter a sentence: " << endl;
cin.read(state, 15);
cout << "The sentence entered was:\n";
cout.write(state, cin.gcount());
cout << endl;
```

and

```
//part E
char charArray[12]; //creates an array of 12
cout << "Enter some characters: " << endl;
cin.getline(charArray, 12, 'y');
cout << "Your characters are: " << charArray << endl;
```

Where whatever I enter in part b gets used in part e. I have tried using clear, ignore, and flush but to no avail. Also, the original input gets used in my other functions, as well.
My main is set up like this:

```
int main()
{
    question1();
    question2();
    question3();
}
```

How am I able to enter a fresh input to use in each part and each function?

Comment: Why are you reading a fixed number of characters instead of using `std::getline`?  If you insist on truncating the input this way, but it is still line-based, then you can call `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')` after the read.  But that's so clunky.  In most cases, `std::string` and `std::getline` are more than sufficient for programs like yours.

Comment: Because that is how the example worked in my textbook.

Comment: @e-bird14 Use it as a doorstop or paperweight, then. (Or give it as a present to someone who you \*really\* dislike with a big grin.)

Comment: The suggestion @paddy mentioned above worked. Hopefully, I will learn how to use this stuff better in the future, though.